# Align bootstrap cards with filter forms on the left

Tags: html, css, angular, sass, bootstrap-5

I am trying to align the cards using `row` and `col-` classes from bootstrap. The first three work as its supposed to but the fourth one doesnt do what i want it to do. Does anyone have an idea as to why this is happening and maybe also have a solution for me?

[The problem in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6JBJ.png)

this is my code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="form">
        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-input" placeholder="Search anything...">
        <span class="left-pan"><i class="fa fa-microphone"></i></span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="mobile-filter">
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <div class="form-check">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="flexCheckDefault">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">
                Default checkbox
              </label>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="form-check">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="flexCheckDefault">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">
                Default checkbox
              </label>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="form-check">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="flexCheckDefault">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">
                Default checkbox
              </label>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="form-check">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="flexCheckDefault">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">
                Default checkbox
              </label>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="form-check">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="flexCheckDefault">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">
                Default checkbox
              </label>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div>
          <div class="border-bottom"></div>
          <ul class="list-group">
            <label for="customRange1" class="form-label">Price per hour</label>
            <input type="range" class="form-range" id="customRange1">
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div>
          <ul class="list-group">
            <label for="customRange1" class="form-label">Price per hour</label>
            <input type="range" class="form-range" id="customRange1">
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
      </div>
      <div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <section id="sidebar">
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <div class="form-check">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="flexCheckDefault">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">
                Default checkbox
              </label>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="form-check">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="flexCheckDefault">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">
                Default checkbox
              </label>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="form-check">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="flexCheckDefault">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">
                Default checkbox
              </label>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="form-check">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="flexCheckDefault">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">
                Default checkbox
              </label>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="form-check">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="flexCheckDefault">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">
                Default checkbox
              </label>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div>
        <div class="border-bottom"></div>
        <ul class="list-group">
          <label for="customRange1" class="form-label">Price per hour</label>
          <input type="range" class="form-range" id="customRange1">
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div>
        <ul class="list-group">
          <label for="customRange1" class="form-label">Price per hour</label>
          <input type="range" class="form-range" id="customRange1">
        </ul>
      </div>
    </section>

    <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-3 col-xxl-3 boat" *ngFor="let boat of boats">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="/{{ boat.src }}" class="card-img-top" alt="{{ boat.name }}">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">{{ boat.name }}</h5>
          <p class="card-text">{{ boat.description }}</p>
          <p>{{ boat.city }}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the scss file that goes with it:

```
.form {
  position: relative;
}

.form .fa-search {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  color: #9ca3af;
}

.form span {
  position: absolute;
  right: 17px;
  top: 13px;
  padding: 2px;
  border-left: 1px solid #d1d5db;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.left-pan {
    padding-left: 7px;
  }

  .left-pan i {
    padding-left: 10px;
  }

  .form-input {
    height: 55px;
    text-indent: 33px;
    border-radius: $br-160;
  }

  .form-input:focus {
    box-shadow: $shadow-black-lg;
    border: $b-1 $b-solid $grey;
  }

  .card {
    margin-top: $m;
    width: 100%;
    height: 350px;
    border-radius: $br-100;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  .card img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: 50% 50%;
  }

  #sidebar {
    width: 20%;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
  }

  ul {
    padding: 5px;
  }

  li a {
    color: $grey;
  }

  li a:hover {
    color: $tertiary;
  }

  .navbar-nav {
    margin-left: 35%;
  }

  .nav-item {
    padding-left: 20px;
  }

  #mobile-filter {
    display: none;
  }


  .boat {
    padding-left: $p-xs;
    padding-right: $p-xs;
  }
```

All help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good start, you should treat the **whole width** as row - then set col-4 vs col-8 to sidebar and your main content or right respectively.

Your forth boat is sliding because... well, it has space there! If you set it's (all boats) container to be col-8 of the whole screen, you can then create flex or grids inside as you will **and** it won't let your items to slide outside of defined space - it will wrap element down, moving it below first card or allow you to make eg. infinite horizontal scroll with all boats being visible in one row.

Comment: I read this a couple times and I’m not sure I understand exactly what you mean :/

Does this mean I have to put the boats in a separate container inside the main container or am I understanding this wrong?

Comment: Yes! I would see it like this - 
there is a container that holds everything, inside (from the top) is eg. row with full width search and nav. Then we have another row/container that holds 2 big elements - left sidebar and right/main content in choosen ratio col-4/8. 
You can have multiple bigger blocks/containers in you project and you precise them from most overal shapes that you eye can get from looking at layout to defining how smaller tags/checkboxes are going to act towards their parents (which are their containers).

Comment: Would it look something like this:
`<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
            <div class="sidebar col-4"></div>
            <div class="boats col-8"></div>
      </div>
</div>`

Comment: @magicalassembler check out this: https://codepen.io/Aerogirl/pen/eYLWKpE?editors=1100
- it ain't pretty but I forced the basic gid you want. You can control independently sidebar (make it sticky, float, staying in the same place and nothing sliding under - no problemo!) and at the same time you have limited space container that keeps your main guts together. If you want to build something full width below both sidebar and right panel - add it below container containing those, if adding something below but not wanting it to spill - keep it in right col-8 container.

Comment: FYI, in the example I've changed the col-8 to col-9 (and sidebar to col-3) because it's more like your example. Also note that I deleted some styling from your sidebar - it's container limits us to 1/3 of the window so it itself should take default 100% of it.

Comment: Aaah yes, it is working exactly how I want it too. Thank you very much and bless you richly!